# How to fix 'Projection operator not supported' error on CosmosDB for MongoDB api?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, azure-cosmosdb

I try to deploy a java spring application on azure.
This application uses a local MongoDB 4.0. I try to replace it with Azure CosmosDB. Connection is OK but running my application tests gives following error:

> "http://org.springframework.data .mongodb.UncategorizedMongoDbException: Query failed with error code 2 and error message 'Projection operator not supported.' on server …http://...azure.com:10255 ; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoQueryException: Query failed with error code 2 and error message 'Projection operator not supported.'"
>   Projection operator seems to be generated by MongoRepository class.

```java
    import org.springframework.data .mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;
    import org.springframework.data .mongodb.repository.Query;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

    @Repository
    public interface UserRepository extends MongoRepository<User, UUID>, UserRegexSearch{

        public Optional<User> findByEmail(String email);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

[Protocol support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb-feature-support#protocol-support) for Azure Cosmos DB's API for MongoDB is compatible with MongoDB server version 3.2 by default and under Public Preview for v3.4. Version 4.0 is currently not supported but please Up Vote and Comment on the following UserVoice entry: [Support for transactions via Mongo 4.0 API](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/suggestions/35324563-support-for-transactions-via-mongo-4-0-api)